Requiero cambiar una parte de un HTML recuperado e insertado en otro HTML


Les planteo mi problemática. Recupero el contenido de un HTML genérico (footer.html), ubicado en un dominio midominio.com, y ese contenido lo inserto dentro de otro HTML (index.html), en su tag ````, archivo también ubicado en midominio.com
Luego de recuperar el contenido de footer.html, requiero modificar dos cadenas de texto, por medio de una función, en la que paso como parámetros los valores que me interesa que queden en el <footer>, pero esto último no está funcionando.
Uso jQuery para leer el footer.html y cargarlo en <footer>
function textoFooter(titulo, autor){
        $('footer').load('https://midominio.com/footer.html', function (response) {
        var txt = response.replace("TITULOUAPA", titulo).replace("AUTOR", autor);

        console.log(txt);
        console.log(response);
    });
}

La función textoFooter() la ejecuto al final del index.html, de la siguiente manera
        textoFooter("Prácticas saludables", "Juan Pérez");

Pero la ejecución de la función solo deja el texto original de footer.html. En la consola sí se ve el cambio hecho al texto.
Agradeceré su ayuda.

Creo que hay algunos detalles en la función. Primero hay que definir el identificador si es por id entonces debe ser $('#footer'), si es por class entonces debería ser $('.footer'). Definido esto entonces lo que sigue es sustituir el contenido html con el texto procesado quedando tu script de la siguiente forma (en caso de ser por id):
function textoFooter(titulo, autor){
        $('#footer').load('https://midominio.com/footer.html', function (response) {
        var txt = response.replace("TITULOUAPA", titulo).replace("AUTOR", autor);

        console.log(txt);
        console.log(response);

        $('#footer').html(txt);
    });
}


Y acaso no existe la etiqueta <footer> ???

Agregué la ejecución de $('footer').html(txt) y ya funcionó correctamente.
Como comenta Yussef, el tag footer existe y es el que utilizo para colocar el texto, no necesito un id.

Eso no te va a funcionar nunca, tienes 2 errores:
1.- Un string es inmutable, no puedes modificarlo. Pero puedes reasignar con un nuevo string a la variable que lo contiene.
Esto:
 var txt = response.replace("TITULOUAPA", titulo).replace("AUTOR", autor);

Crea un nuevo string llamado txt con los cambios realizados, pero nunca se modificó el response. Tu deberías haber reasignado, así:
 response = response.replace("TITULOUAPA", titulo).replace("AUTOR", autor);

2.- Lo de arriba tampoco hara que funcione tu código como tú esperas. El callback de la función load() se ejecuta una vez se ha insertado el html, es decír, alterar el response no tiene sentido, ya está hecho el cambio. Podría haber funcionado si el callback se ejecuta luego de la solicitud ajax pero previo a la inserción
La solución:
Es usar un $.get, realizar los cambios y luego insertar:
function textoFooter(titulo, autor) {
    $.get("footer.html", function(response) {
        response= response.replace("TITULOUAPA", titulo).replace("AUTOR", autor);
        $("footer").append(response);
    });
}

